# Google Maps plugin - How to trigger an info window

Tags: templating, plugin-smartmap, plugin-googlemaps

I'm migrating Smart Map over to the Google Maps plugin, and I want to open a popup on button click. But it seems there is no JS method available to open an info window.

Here's how it was done in Smart Map:

- [Trigger Info window in Smart Map using external navigation](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/27410/trigger-info-window-in-smart-map-using-external-navigation)

How can I do the same thing with the Google Maps plugin?

Comment: I might need to add a small method to the new plugin. Let me take a closer look and get back to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of Google Maps **4.0.1**, there is a new [`getInfoWindow`](https://plugins.doublesecretagency.com/google-maps/dynamic-maps/javascript-methods/#getinfowindow-infowindowid) method in JavaScript. This makes it easy to retrieve and manipulate existing info windows.

Additionally, I've written a guide for [Opening Info Windows...](https://plugins.doublesecretagency.com/google-maps/guides/opening-info-windows/)

Hope that helps! :)